# Change class when string is found in PHP

Tags: php, class

I have:

```
$keyword = 'blue';
```

I want to insert a special class when in a string the system found `blue`.

---

## For example:

`This sky is <span class="blue">blue</a>`.

`This pear is green`.

---

## I have actually:

```
$string = "The sky is blue."; 
if (stripos($string, $keyword) !== false) {
    // The string is found, now change the class
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you considered using javascript instead?

Comment: I prefer to use PHP as it is during an ajax call to a PHP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$keyword = 'blue';
$replace = 'green';
$string = "The sky is blue."; 
if (stripos($string, $keyword) !== false) {
   $string = str_ireplace(array($keyword), $replace , $string);
}
```

Comment: No really. I want to replace `blue` by `<span class="myClass">blue</span>`, if find.

Comment: That's what you should put as a value of $replace.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regexps, as in:

```
function format_keywords($html, $keywords) {
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        $keyword = preg_quote($keyword);
        $html = preg_replace("/\b$keyword\b/i", "<span class=\"$keyword\">$keyword</span>", $html);
    }
    return $html;
}
```

For example, this:

```
format_keywords("This sky is blue.", array("is", "blue"));
```

Would yield:

```
This sky <span class="is">is</span> <span class="blue">blue</span>?
```

Note that `This` has not been recognized, thanks to the `\b` delimiters.

See the documentation:

- https://php.net/preg_quote
- https://php.net/preg_replace